# php mysql form while statement populating drop down with selected

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am having a bit of a problem with a data populated drop down selection.  I am populating a form with the data from 2 tables using to different queries and a nested while statement.  The first gives the output of the contact information, the second is just populating the state field.  They both work fine, but I am trying to use a ternary operator to change the selected option to the correct one from the data base, and I think I am not selecting the right data.  If I try to have a join on the 2 tables it either outputs only the states that exist in contacts, or it outputs all the states plus doubles for any records in contacts.  I feel like I am pretty close here.  Here is the php;

```
        $dialogValue = $_POST['dataOpen'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM contacts prc
        JOIN states as st
        ON (prc.stateId = st.idStates)
        WHERE (idContacts ='" . $selectionValue ."')";
        $statesSQL = "SELECT * FROM states";
        $prcresult = $conn->query($sql);
        $statesResult = $conn->query($statesSQL);
        if ($prcresult->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($prcrow = $prcresult->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo
                    "<form>"
                        ."<fieldset>"
                            ."<label for='name'>Name</label>"
                            ."<input type='text' name='firstName' value='" . $prcrow["firstName"] ."'>"
                            ."<input type='text' name='lastName' value='" . $prcrow["lastName"] ."'>"
                            ."<input type='text' name='address1' value='" . $prcrow["address1"] ."'>"
                            ."<input type='text' name='address2' value='" . $prcrow["address2"] ."'>"
                            ."<input type='text' name='city' value='" . $prcrow["city"] ."'>";
                    if ($statesResult->num_rows > 0) {
                        echo "<select>";
                        // output data of each row
                        while($strow = $statesResult->fetch_assoc()) {
                            //echo '<option value="'.$value.'" '.(($value=='United States')?'selected="selected"':"").'>'.$value.'</option>';
                            echo "<option value='" .$strow["idStates"] ."'" .(($strow["idState"]==$prcrow["statesId"])?'selected="selected"':"").">" .$strow["state"] ."</option>";
                            }
                    }                                   
            }
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }
        /*if ($statesResult->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $statesResult->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo

                "<option value='" .$row["idStates"] ."'>" .$row["state"] ."</option>";
            }
        }else{
        echo "o results";
        }*/
        echo
            "</select></fieldset>
                </form>";
        $conn->close();
        ?>
```

The tables that I am working with have this structure;

this is contacts

```
        idContacts  
        firstName    
        lastName       
        address1       
        address2    
        city     
        stateId     
        zip    
        phone1      
        phone2     
        email
```

this is states;

```
        idStates
        state
```

They are joined where contacts.stateId = states.idStates on the first query $sql  not sure if I need the second query or not...

Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.  The previous query had to be used first in the ternary operator.  like this;

```
    while($strow = $statesResult->fetch_assoc()) {
                //echo '<option value="'.$value.'" '.(($value=='United States')?'selected="selected"':"").'>'.$value.'</option>';
                echo "<option value='" .$strow["idStates"] ."'" .(($prcrow["statesId"]===$strow["idState"])?'selected="selected"':"").">" .$strow["state"] ."</option>";
                }
        }
```